# Convert string representation of colors back to list

Tags: python, pandas, csv, literals

I had data where one column was a list of numbers, but when saving to a CSV, I guess this got stored as a string. **I want to convert this list of strings back to a list of lists.**

So here's what my data looks like now:

```
import pandas as pd 
from ast import literal_eval

colors = ["(120, 120, 80)", "(90, 10, 100)"]
names = ["name1", "name2"]
data = {
    "colors":colors,
    "names":names
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

And from reading Stackoverflow, I tried the literal eval method but it did not work:

```
try:
  df['colors'] = literal_eval( df['colors'].tolist() )
except ValueError as e:
  print(e)
```

I get a malformed string error.

Comment: @Dan From the Python docs on `ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)`: "Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None.

This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values oneself. It is not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex expressions, for example involving operators or indexing."

Comment: @ChristopherPeisert thanks for the info!

Comment: `[[int(channel) for channel in re.findall(r'\d+', color)] for color in colors]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `literal_eval()` is a good approach. The issue is that it needs to be applied to each sub-list (string) individually. A pythonic approach would be to use a list comprehension as follows:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> colors = ["(120, 120, 80)", "(90, 10, 100)"]
>>> colors = [literal_eval(x) for x in colors]
>>> colors
[(120, 120, 80), (90, 10, 100)]
```

To get a `list` of `list` instead of a `list` of `tuple`, you could use:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> colors = ["(120, 120, 80)", "(90, 10, 100)"]
>>> colors = [list(literal_eval(x)) for x in colors]
>>> colors
[[120, 120, 80], [90, 10, 100]]
```

The Python documentation for [ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) states:

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
>   literal or container display. The string or node provided may only
>   consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes,
>   numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python
>   values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values
>   oneself. It is not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex
>   expressions, for example involving operators or indexing.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this for each of the columns:

```
col = [int(val) for val in colors.replace("(","").replace(")","").split(",")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `re.findall` to extract digits and `apply` over the series:

```
import re
df['colors'].apply(lambda str : [int(s) for s in re.findall(r'\d+',str) ]).tolist()

#  [[120, 120, 80], [90, 10, 100]]
```